# Is quantum field theory impredicative?

Tags: logic

We define a field as a physical quantity assigned to each point of spacetime.

In turn, spacetime is often defined or understood as "all there is", where field is.

So logically I wonder if this is an impredicative theory or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "impredicative"?

Comment: a definition is said to be impredicative if it invokes (mentions or quantifies over) the set being defined, or (more commonly) another set which contains the thing being defined. We define the field on spacetime, the spacetime on the field itself.  a self-referencing definition...

Comment: Isn't this a better question for Physics SE?

Comment: Yes, but would like to get an answer from a "logic" expert

Comment: While I can understand your hope to get an answer "from a *logic* expert", I think it is not mathematical logic that is at issue here.  A philosophical analysis might be in order, but would probably be of monograph length or more to present the possible fallacy of a self-referencing definition in physics.  In math we are generally quite satisfied to have foundational notions like "set" or "variable" that are not defined per se but are the subject of axiomatic treatments.

Answer (score 1):

*Comemnt*

> A definition is said to be [impredicative](http://www.iep.utm.edu/predicat/) if it generalizes over a totality to which the entity being defined belongs.

Example of impredicative definition :

> Let $n$ be the least natural number such that $n$ cannot be written as the sum of at most four cubes.

The generalization implicit in the definition of $n$ (the *least number* ...) is over "all" numbers.

About your example, we may assume that *spacetime* is the universe of discourse and that the physical quantity defined as a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)) is such that has a value for each point in space and time.

If so, we cannot circularly define spacetime in terms of fields.

---

Impredicative definitions are allowed from a "platonist" point of view because e.g. numbers are considering abstract objects existing irrespective of our knowledge of them.

They are not allowed from a "constructive" point of view where abstract objects are "product" (in some way) of the mathematician activity : in this sense, we cannot postulate their properties before having "constructed" them.

What about spacetime in physics ? Is "constructed" ot it is "out there" from the start ?